# Unable to see data after data migration from SQL Server to Azure Cosmos db

Tags: sql, azure, nosql, azure-cosmosdb, azure-data-factory

I used Azure Data Factory to migrate data from SQL Server to Azure CosmosDB. In Data Factory, it shows the status is Ready and succeeded (100%). Retry attempt is 1.

But I am not able to see any data in CosmosDB after the migration is done. It also shows an error message from CosmosDB that

> "code" : 500, "body": "Detected corrupted documents without _id identifier, verify that you are only storing documents through Mongo protocol and not SQL API or DocumentDB SDK."}

A few things I did differently is that

- I un-selected the "column name is selected" option, which I assume the data will migrate from scratch.
- I converted from SQL Server to Cosmos DB - mongo db. I am not sure if it will make the data corrupted because it is basically converting from SQL to NO-SQL.

Please let me know your thoughts. Thank you!

Comment: Hi,any updates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From this [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db#supported-capabilities) you could see Azure Cosmos DB connector supports only Cosmos DB SQL API(document db). And the type in the [Dataset properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-cosmos-db#dataset-properties) need to be set to `DocumentDbCollection`.

Azure Document DB and Azure Mongo DB are both `NO-SQL` database in the Azure Cosmos DB.However, there are many [differences](https://medium.com/@thomasweiss_io/azure-documentdb-vs-mongodb-6d5806c16239) between them.

Hope it helps you.